# What is a legalized copy?

Tags: russian-citizens, luxembourg

I am from Russia, since September I move to Luxembourg to study. At the moment I am preparing documents for obtaining permission for stay in Luxembourg. In official lists of documents I see the requirement to present **legalized** copies of documents like birth certificate and bank certificate.

I am interested to know whether 'legalized' means only notarized copies or documents with apostile. To my mind apostile seems to be more formal and thus more appropriate but I want to make sure.

Comment: This sounds vaguely like "[EU English](https://www.eca.europa.eu/Other%20publications/EN_TERMINOLOGY_PUBLICATION/EN_TERMINOLOGY_PUBLICATION.pdf)," i.e. a mistranslation from a Continental language, like *actorness* or *valorise* or *sickness insurance* or *comitology*. I can't quite place it, though.

Comment: https://guichet.public.lu/entreprises/en/ressources-humaines/recrutement/ressortissant-pays-tiers/etudiant/index.html

Comment: Actually I see that in case of doubt a copy (I think ordinary notarized one) can be requested to authenticate so I suppose using apostile is more convenient and reliable.

Comment: Here’s the document where you can find all specified documents.

Comment: @PolinaNovikova, Added some more details on the specifics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: So the final answer is:**

You should really contact the Luxembourg Consulate/Embassy. They can recommend a translator who's also a local notary public.

Because according to the instructions, if it's not in German, French, or English, a translation must be added to it. Note that you will also need to visit that local notary public in person because he/she will need to verify your identity as well.

Then once that's done, you'll need to give it to the Consulate/Embassy so that they can notarize it a second time, or post a seal on it. That's what they mean when they say "double legalization".

However, I am not sure if you'll have to visit the Consulate/Embassy in person as well. You may have to. Either way, they'll be able to tell you that when you call them.

Note that the new stamps/seals/signatures affixed to the photocopy of the document/added translation by either the notary public, the translator, the consulate/embassy, or yourself, won't be valid if you photocopy them (that would defeat their authentication purpose).

In other words, by verifying and certifying a photocopy with an original signature/stamp/seal, it then becomes an original document. Unfortunately, a birth certificate with a Russian apostille won't be enough. It's an original document, yes, and Russia seems to be a signatory of the right treaty, but unfortunately, it's in Russian, so it won't satisfy their language requirement. That's why you'll need to do all that extra work of "double legalization".

Now, it may be possible that the Consulate/Embassy is able to provide all those services themselves, the local notary public, the official translation, and the additional Consulate/Embassy certification. This could make things much more convenient for you, so it may be worth asking if they do it all.

---

**Previous answer**

Thus far, [these](https://wwwfr.uni.lu/etudiants/demandes_d_admission_reinscriptions/conditions_d_eligibilite_pour_etudiants_non_ue) are the requirements I found for the diploma, and I couldn't find the ones you mentioned regarding the birth certificate.

> Pour postuler à l'Université du Luxembourg, les copies du diplôme et du relevé de notes que vous devez joindre à votre dossier DOIVENT IMPERATIVEMENT être [apostillées](https://wwwfr.uni.lu/etudiants/informations_utiles_de_a_a_z/apostille) ou [doublement légalisées](https://wwwfr.uni.lu/etudiants/informations_utiles_de_a_a_z/qu_est_ce_qu_une_double_legalisation) (tampons et signatures originaux-pas de photocopies).

So in this particular case, they very clearly say that for the diploma can be doubly legalized **"or"** have an apostile. However, I have no idea if they would treat a birth certificate the same way they'd treat a diploma.

Their definition of [apostillées](https://wwwfr.uni.lu/etudiants/informations_utiles_de_a_a_z/apostille)

> **Apostille**
>
> Si vos documents ont été établis dans un des pays signataires de la convention de la Haye du 5 octobre 1961 supprimant l’exigence de la légalisation des actes publics, il suffit que les documents soient munis d’une apostille. L’apostille est un sceau spécial appliqué par une autorité (l’Ambassade) pour certifier la véracité du document officiel.

Their definition of [doublement légalisées](https://wwwfr.uni.lu/etudiants/informations_utiles_de_a_a_z/qu_est_ce_qu_une_double_legalisation)

> **Qu'est-ce qu'une "double légalisation"**
>
> Si le pays qui a émis les documents n'a pas signé la Convention de la Haye, les documents doivent être
>
> authentifiés par l'autorité locale compétente du pays d'origine
>   et légalisés par l'Ambassade ("double légalisation").
>   Dans le cadre de cette procédure de "double légalisation",
>
> le document doit être d'abord authentifié par les autorités du pays qui a délivré le document, suivant une procédure propre à cet Etat. Les autorités authentifient la signature et la qualité de la personne qui a délivré le document. En d'autres termes, elle permet de vérifier si la signature apposée sur le document est bien celle de la personne qui l'a signé et si cette personne a bien la qualité qu'elle prétend avoir.
>
> Ensuite, le document devra être légalisé par les autorités du pays qui recevra le document, à savoir l'Ambassade ou le Consulat qui représente le Luxembourg dans le pays dans lequel le document a été émis. Si aucune d'Ambassade du Luxembourg n'est présente dans votre pays, veuillez prendre contact avec l'Ambassade de Belgique ou l'Ambassade des Pays-Bas.
>   Exemple:
>
> Avec la copie de votre diplôme, vous deverz vous rendre dans l'Université qui a édité votre diplôme et faire signer la copie par une personne responsable (=légalisation). Ensuite, vous devrez vous rendre à l'Ambassade pour que la signature de la personne responsable de l'Université soit authentifiée (= double légalisation)
>
> Attention: Si les documents ne sont pas rédigés dans les langues allemande, française ou anglaise, une traduction conforme par un traducteur assermenté doit être jointe.